# Resizing a UIStackView using AutoLayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistackview

I have the following setup in my storyboard. I want the selected `UIStackView` to stretch across it's parents view so its right edge is the same distance away from the edge of the screen as the left edge.

Control dragging from the stackview to it's parent view and selecting "Trailing space to container margin" doesn't do what I thought it would (I am very new to auto layout). What is the correct way to resize this stackview? TIA

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to center the stackview horizontally in its superview?

Comment: @marosoaie Yes, I would like it to be centered and have it take up the rest of the horizontal space of its super view (so that there is equal spacing on each size of the stackview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control click and drag form your stackView to it's superview. Then pick **Center Horizontally**. Adding a leading constraint should be sufficient.